# javascript: быстрый способ записать в элементы массива с заданным шагом

Tags: javascript, массивы, оптимизация, производительность

подскажите есть ли более производительный способ чем решение в лоб для записи в массив с фиксированным шагом значения

т.е. на входе есть массив `arr`, начальная позиция `start`, шаг `step` и само значение `value`

есть ли что-то более производительное, чем:

```
for (let i = start; i < table.length; i += step) {
    table[i] = value;
}
```

Comment: Вы говорите про скорость работы или про сам код (быстрее писать)?

Comment: @ΝNL993, про производительность

Comment: простой цикл все еще самое производительное решение

Comment: @Grundy, просто подумалось, что может есть аналог fill, просто для скриптовых языков зачастую функции работают гораздо быстрее

Comment: Будет быстрее, если массив объявить, как типизированный. На пример, `let table = new uint8Array(length);`. В данном случае ячейки должны быть целым числом в пределах **0 - 255**, где **length** - длина массива.

Comment: @Опан, какая именно часть цикла должна стать быстрее в этом случае?

Comment: В общей сложности быстрее.